# adding unique identifier For-Each object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

i have a simple PowerShell based script, that iterate each object using the for-each loop statement:

```
$customers = @("Jhon","Benny","Dave","Moris","Janet","Glenn")

 foreach ($customer in $customers) {
   "$customer = " + $customer. Length
 }
```

But i am trying to find a way to add some kind of identifier for the objects, which will be unique, no matter the PowerShell session. like the identity column in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE hr.customers (
    customer_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
```

After reviewing number of PowerShell documentation, i have found a cmdlet named:

```
[guid]::NewGuid()
```

That seems like what i need.

Is this the right cmdlet to use in my case?

Comment: That isn't a cmdlet, it's simply calling the `Guid.NewGuid()` method that .NET offers (PowerShell being essentially a .NET application). Note that this will yield unique values on *every* invocation, so even producing the same list in the same session again will result in different values.

Comment: Worth noting that the equivalent cmdlet would be: `New-Guid`

Comment: I assume you have already found your answer, using a GUID for each user? `$customers | ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{ User = $_; ID = [guid]::NewGuid() }`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, can you please elaborate, why did you create a custom object? i planned to use the New-Guid cmdlet foreach object, with an array.

Comment: well, you need to associate each user with their GUID. custom objects are the easiest way to do it. reg. `New-Guid` and `[guid]::NewGuid()` there is no difference which one you want to use, `New-Guid` is just a wrapper for the .NET Api.

Answer (score 0):

There's good information in the comments on the question.
Let me build on them by offering a [`class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Classes)-based solution that constructs objects with an `.Identity` property that is initialized with a [GUID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Guid) on construction:

```bash
class Customer {
  [guid]   $Identity = [guid]::NewGuid()  # instance property with unique ID
  [string] $Name                          # get/set name property.
  Customer([string] $name) { # constructor
    $this.Name = $name
  }
}

# For each customer, create a [Customer] instance whose .Identity
# property contains a unique value (GUID)
@("Jhon","Benny","Dave","Moris","Janet","Glenn").ForEach({ [Customer]::new($_) })
```

Sample output:

```bash
Identity                             Name
--------                             ----
40c2d6bb-aac8-4c90-9a1a-f886128ae4f8 Jhon
baaba12a-9f98-40e8-b8ea-042efdc27dda Benny
f22a50b5-1654-4b01-8934-1488cea46d5c Dave
a211623f-30cc-40b2-b5d7-311260fdf95e Moris
8173d1ed-3ec8-4f4f-afc4-80499d2ffeda Janet
0f4d998b-f09a-48f0-9f5d-41b5dcbc9f50 Glenn
```

Note:

- **Unless you *persist* the resulting objects and from then on work with the persisted representations, your objects will have different identities every time you run this code**.
- Properties in PowerShell `class` definitions are technically invariably read/write, because property getters and setters aren't supported (as of PowerShell v7.3.2); therefore `.Identity` can technically be overwritten later (but obviously shouldn't be). [GitHub issue #2219](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2219) proposes implementing property getters/setters in a future version.

Answer (score -2):

Create code like below which creates a table with rows and columns

```
$customers = @("Jhon","Benny","Dave","Moris","Janet","Glenn")
$table = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
$length = 0
 foreach ($customer in $customers) {
    $length += 1
    $newRow = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Customer -NotePropertyValue $customer
    $newRow | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Length -NotePropertyValue $length
    $table.Add($newRow)  | Out-Null
 }
$table | Format-Table
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it doesn't even attempt to answer the question (adding unique identifiers to the objects)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  : You do not understand the question.  The OP wants to put results into a table but did not know what type of object to use so thought he could do it with NewGuid.

Comment: Really? I thought the SQL table was just an example of "something similar". Post says "_like_ the identity column in SQL server"

Comment: OP wanted to generate a GUID to use ACROSS PS sessions. Not sure there's anything suitable unless you simply formulate your own formula to generate a GUID based on the name and if you do that, why not pipe in unique names in the first place? This is almost certainly a good reason to use a proper database like SQL.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen : OP used LIKE.  Said : But i am trying to find a way to add some kind of identifier for the objects, which will be unique, no matter the PowerShell session. like the identity column in SQL Server:

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear in that matter, but i looked for some kind of a unique identifier to be use in my PowerShell loop statement, LIKE the identity column in SQL Server, which i use frequently. @MathiasR.Jessen,@jdweng, thanks for your help, it's very much appreciated.